# How do I satisfy a warning for casting a collection in java/jsp

Tags: java, jsp, collections

In my JSP I get a warning for this cast

```
<%
  Collection<Server> svr = (Collection<Server>)request.getAttribute("serverCollection");
%>
```

`instanceOf` doesn't seem to work here

Comment: What is the warning content ?

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to 
  Collection<Server>
 - Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to 
  Collection<Server>

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Comment: Should I suppress or try to fix the problem? Is this an inherent problem/warning for this type of utilization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%
    @SupressWarnings("unchecked")
    Collection<Server> svr = (Collection<Server>)request.getAttribute("serverCollection");
%>
```

BTW, using scriplets is not very good thing, read this [thread about avoiding scriplets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Answer (score 1):

You can't "satisfy" that warning. It is an unchecked cast, and you can't really do anything about it since the method returns an `Object`.

If you're absolutely positive the attribute will always contain a `Collection<Server>` you can add a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JSTL instead of scriptlets. It would look like:

```
<c:set var="svr" value="${requestScope['serverCollection']}"/>
```

Comment: @Marshll187: it would go in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid this warning (except by suppressing it). The problem is that Java at runtime is only able to check that the object is of type `Collection` at runtime when casting. It cannot check that it is of type `Collection<Server>`. That is what the error means.